# Interpretation of Epithet in English

Tags: rhetoric

> **Epithet** is an adjective or adjective phrase appropriately qualifying a
>   subject (noun) by naming a key or important characteristic of the
>   subject, as in "laughing happiness," "sneering contempt," "untroubled
>   sleep," "peaceful dawn," and "lifegiving water."
>
> Source: https://course-notes.org/english/rheotical_devices/epithet

I have a hard time understanding all the epithets here.

"laughing happiness" someone is laughing with happiness?

"sneering contempt" someone shows contempt in an open way?

"untroubled sleep" someone sleeps without being interrupted?

"peaceful dawn" dawn that gives you a sense of peacefulness?

"lifegiving water" water that makes you refreshed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not call any of those "epithets". They are merely noun phrases containing descriptive adjectives. In my experience, an epithet is:

Firstly, a descriptive noun, adjective or phrase which **replaces** the name of a person or thing, mostly a person.  Examples:

- "Achilles" (the red one)  was an epithet, not the actual name, of the protagonist of Homer's *Iliad*.
- "Augustus" (the honored one) was an epithet of Octavian, the first Roman Emperor.
- "The Babe", "The Bambino" (Italian for baby), and "The Sultan of Swat" were all epithets of the baseball player Babe Ruth
- "Iron man" was an epithet of baseball player Lou Gehrig, noted for his endurance.
- "Tricky Dick" was an epithet of US President Nixon.
- "The Donald" is an epithet of current US President Trump.
- "The Widow-maker" was an epithet of any of several famously violent horses.
- "The Sun King" was an epithet of Louis XIV of France
- "Stalin" (the steel one) was an epithet (self-conferred)  of the Russian dictator.

Secondly, an Epithet can be an adjective or descriptive phrase added to a name, distinguishing the person referred to from others with the same basic name.

- "Alexander the Great" distinguishes the conqueror from any of the many other people named Alexander (repeller of men).
- Alfonso the Wise (Alfonso X of Spain) distinguishes  him from other Spanish rulers of the same name
- Æthelred the Unræd (Old English *unræd*, meaning "un-advised or ill advised) was an early King of England.  His epithet plays on the word ræd (advice) which forms the last part of his name, as it does in the name of Alfred the Great (advised by elves) it is sometimes now given as "the unready" which is a distortion, although not inappropriate.
- "Shoeless Joe" was an epithet of baseball player Joe Jackson.
- "The Divine Sarah" was an epithet of singer Sarah Vaughn.
- "William the Bastard" was an epithet of William I of England (also known as William the conqueror)
- "Lucky Jim" was an epithet of James Watson, co-discoverer of DNA. (Based on his begin in the right place at the right time to be part of this discovery, and on his having had several stokes of good fortune early in his career.)
- "Lucky Jack" is an epithet of the fictional character Jack Aubrey, in the naval novels of Patrick O'Brian.

Thirdly, an epithet can be an adjective or noun phrase used to replace or qualify the name of a group of people. This kid of epithet is more often than not derogatory if not insulting.

- "Canuck" means a person from Canada, originally from a particular part of Canada.
- "Yankee" means a person from the United States, originally from New England.
- "Dago" is an insulting term for a person from Italy, Spain, or Portugal.
- "Hun" was used as an epithet for a German during World Wars I and II.

And finally, derived fro the third group, an epithet can be a general term of abuse which replaces a name or description.

- You bastard!
- That SOB!

---

As to the adjectival phrases, which i maintain are not epithets, in the question:

- laughing happiness = Happiness expressed in laughter, or provoking laughter.
- sneering contempt = contempt expressed by means of, or along with a sneering expression or tone of voice, or figuratively, contempt which mocks and belittles its object.
- untroubled sleep = sleep which is undisturbed, particularly which is not afflicted by nightmares or mental regrets.
- peaceful dawn,= a calm quiet dawn, before many animals or humans are about, making noise. Figuratively, a new start, a calm beginning to something.
- lifegiving water = water which refreshes, particularity one who is suffering from significant thirst, perhaps even thirst sufficient to endanger life. The image is of a person dying of thirst, offered water, or of plants wilting from drought being watered. This is a very common poetic phrase and image.

Comment: Thanks so much.  A great learning experience from you.